# Turing Machine & Recursively enumerable languages.

Tags: computer-science, computability

Suppose Turing Machine(TM) M and language L.


L = { "M" | M has as input strings which $∈$ $\{0,1\}^{*}$ and terminate at a maximum of $512^{512}$ steps}


Is L a recursively enumerable language?

Comment: What was your attempt? What do you think?

Comment: I got it. By definition, loops don't terminate in a given number of steps.

Comment: Based on the definition of the recursively enumerable languages(there exists a turing machine  that will halt and accept when presented with any string in the language as input but may either halt and reject or loop forever when presented with a string not in the language), I would say that L isn't a recursively enumerable language. After this number of steps the string could have been acceptept or rejected but certainly not loop forever. So we could have: no loop, no acceptance, no rejection, which means not a recursively enumerable language.

Comment: Use one other definition of recursively enumerable what does its name suggests?

Comment: @Mayank Deora.
I thought that was the most "suitable" or better "applicable" definition on this problem. Trying to think of an approach with the second one appearing on wikipedia(I will avoid to use the textbook because it's in my native language which is not english and there are already enough translation problems :P )

Comment: Does "M has input strings which $\in \{0,1\}^{*}$ and terminate at a maximum of $512^{512}$ steps" mean that there is some input to $M$ that halts in that many steps or does it mean that every input to $M$ halts in that many steps?

Comment: @Quinn Culver
That would be the former.

Answer (score 1):

We define an encoding of a Turing Machine as a set of combinations of all strings of length $\le 512^{512}$. To imagine this let's take an smaller case : $2^2$ steps

Then L would contain combinations of all the strings of length $\le 2^2$   as follows:

 $$0  $$ $$1$$ $$00$$ $$01$$ $$10$$ $$11$$ $$.$$$$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ Each Combination of these strings encodes a turing machine thus representing a turing machine by strings generated by it
We can define this set of turing machine encoding as a power set but of a finite set so it is also finite so it is countable.

Similarly you can prove it for the length$\le 512^{512}$

Since by definition Every recursively enumerable language is countable and because this set of encoding of turing machines is countable ,it is recursively enumerable.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.